# Can you use calcein to stain milk somatic cells and observe them through a fluorescent microscope?

Tags: microscopy, fluorescent-microscopy, milk

I am currently working on an image cytometer that could automatically count somatic cells in milk samples. Can I use Calcein (i.e., C30H26N2O13) to stain the somatic cells? If not, what dye can I use for fluorescent imaging?